# put the name of the people who have some value in some column

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I want to put the name of the people who have some value in some column.

mi df is:

```
name<-c("luis", "John", "Leo")
a1<-c("a","b",NA)
a2<-c("c",NA,"d")
a3<-c(NA,"d","e")

df<-data.frame(name,a1,a2,a3)
```

I want to get a result like this

```
a1: "Luis", "John"
a2: "Luis", "Leon"
a3: "John", "Leo"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `aggregate` + `stack` like below

```
> df[-1] <- ifelse(!is.na(unlist(df[-1])), df$name, NA)

> aggregate(. ~ ind, stack(df[-1]), toString)
  ind     values
1  a1 luis, John
2  a2  luis, Leo
3  a3  John, Leo
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lapply` to subset `df$name` in cases where the value not `is.na`.

```
lapply(df[-1], function(x) df$name[!is.na(x)])
#$a1
#[1] "luis" "John"
#
#$a2
#[1] "luis" "Leo" 
#
#$a3
#[1] "John" "Leo"
```

Or in a different format using `toString` and `stack`.

```
rev(stack(lapply(df[-1], function(x) toString(df$name[!is.na(x)]))))
#  ind     values
#1  a1 luis, John
#2  a2  luis, Leo
#3  a3  John, Leo
```

or

```
sapply(df[-1], function(x) toString(df$name[!is.na(x)]))
#          a1           a2           a3 
#"luis, John"  "luis, Leo"  "John, Leo"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution, based on `purrr::map_dfr`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

map_dfr(df[-1], ~ str_c(df$name[!is.na(.x)], collapse = ", ")) %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything())

#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>   name  value     
#>   <chr> <chr>     
#> 1 a1    luis, John
#> 2 a2    luis, Leo 
#> 3 a3    John, Leo
```

Answer (score 0):

One option in `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -name, names_to = "cn", values_drop_na = TRUE) %>% 
  group_by(cn) %>% 
  summarise(name = toString(name)) %>%
  unite(new, everything(), sep = ": ")
# A tibble: 3 × 1
  new           
  <chr>         
1 a1: luis, John
2 a2: luis, Leo 
3 a3: John, Leo
```